# Redirect Multiple URL's To One Landing Page Using Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

Hello everyone I am attempting to make a basic chrome extension that will take a variable list of url's and redirect them to a different url when visited. Basically they would go to ABC.com-XYZ.com and all urls would instead go to google.com.

This is the code I am using but it does not seem to be working. This is my first time ever trying to build a chrome extension and I got it to block the url's I wanted but then realized I would rather redirect the urls in my variable list to a target landing page.

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Redirect URLS",
    "description": "why go anywhere but google?",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"128":"icon_128.png"},
    "browser_action": {"default icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"},
    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "http://*/", "https://*/"],
    "background": {"scripts": ["blocked_domains.js", "background.js"]}
}
```

**blocked_domains.js**

```
var blocked_domains = [
    "*://*.yahoo.com/*",
    "*://*.sample.com/*",
    "*://*.example.com/*",
    "*://*.vox.com/*"];
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(info) {
      var url = "https://google.com";
      return {redirectUrl: url};
    },
    {
      urls: [blocked_domains]
    },
    ["blocking"])
```

Comment: `blocked_domains` is already an Array. Therefore, in background.js you have to change `urls: [blocked_domains]` for `urls: blocked_domains`.

Comment: This worked thank you so much! Could you point me to a place where I could learn more about this kind of topic and the basics? Also How do I mark your question as accepted? I don't have a check mark on my screen :(

Comment: The best source of information is the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). Keep coding, and if you find any issue again, feel free to ask another question: that's what StackOverflow is for :)